I have an error with my application on Nest JS. This app consist in an Auth module with Register and Login methods
When I run my app, it runs without problems but when I try to register an user I obtain an "Internal server error 500".
This is the error:
[Nest] 27458  - 05/14/2024, 3:33:41 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] user is not allowed to do action [find] on [panaceum.users]
MongoServerError: user is not allowed to do action [find] on [panaceum.users]
at Connection.sendCommand (/home/riwip5-048/panaceum-auth-1/node_modules/mongodb/src/cmap/connection.ts:498:17)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at Connection.command (/home/riwip5-048/panaceum-auth-1/node_modules/mongodb/src/cmap/connection.ts:562:22)
at Server.command (/home/riwip5-048/panaceum-auth-1/node_modules/mongodb/src/sdam/server.ts:310:16)
at executeOperation (/home/riwip5-048/panaceum-auth-1/node_modules/mongodb/src/operations/execute_operation.ts:181:12)
at FindCursor._initialize (/home/riwip5-048/panaceum-auth-1/node_modules/mongodb/src/cursor/find_cursor.ts:78:22)
at FindCursor.[kInit] (/home/riwip5-048/panaceum-auth-1/node_modules/mongodb/src/cursor/abstract_cursor.ts:644:21)
at next (/home/riwip5-048/panaceum-auth-1/node_modules/mongodb/src/cursor/abstract_cursor.ts:717:7)
at Collection.findOne (/home/riwip5-048/panaceum-auth-1/node_modules/mongodb/src/collection.ts:500:17)
at model.Query._findOne (/home/riwip5-048/panaceum-auth-1/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2528:15)
I expect to create an user. Help! Please!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
